# How to add UICollectionView to a UITableview FooterView?

Tags: xcode

I have a tableview with a custom headerView and footerView. I'll like to display a UICollectionView inside the footerView.

Comment: Could you provide additional details about your specific situation by editing your post? Your question and description is a tad sparse.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Collection view inside

`-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`

set collection view data source & Delegate to your view controller.

Show your contents in Collection view Datasources & Write your desired behaviour in Collection view Delegates.

Hope it helps..